# How do I make my Cartodb info windows wider?

Tags: carto, html, cartocss

According to my read of [andrewxhill](https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/8655774) ([more readable version](https://gist.github.com/amandabee/9628190)) I should be able to change the info window size  by adding CSS, like so:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup header with-image" data-cover="true">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-header">
    <div class="cover">
      <div id="spinner"></div>
      <div class="image_not_found"><a href="#/map" class="help">Non-valid picture URL</a></div>
      <span class="separator"></span>
      <h1 class="order1">{{description}}</h1>
      <div class="shadow"></div>
      <img width="100%" src="{{img_url}}" style="height:135px;display:inline" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
      <h4>description</h4>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
      <p>{{name}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>

<style>
div.cartodb-popup {width:417px !important;}
</style>
```

But this has no impact on the width of my info window.

Comment: You definitely want the `<style>` definition *above* the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

```
<style>
div.cartodb-popup.stories {width:417px;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-left:-197px;
    background:url("http://vizzuality.github.io/icij/img/map/infowindow-top.png") no-repeat} 
div.cartodb-popup.stories div.cartodb-popup-content-wrapper{width:407px;
    max-width:407px;
    padding:0 5px 0 50px;
    background:url("http://vizzuality.github.io/icij/img/map/infowindow-content.png") repeat-y} 
div.cartodb-popup.stories div.cartodb-popup-tip-container{width:417px;
    background:url("http://vizzuality.github.io/icij/img/map/infowindow-bottom.png") no-repeat} 
</style>
<div class="cartodb-popup stories">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
      <h4>state</h4>
      <p>{{state}}</p>
      <h4>fatalities_per_100k</h4>
      <p>{{fatalities_per_100k}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

Which is roughly working (and obvs uses a different map). The infowindow background: http://vizzuality.github.io/icij/img/map/infowindow-content.png introduces a blue bar on the left -- you'll want to edit that in your favorite image editor if you just want a white background.

This also works, but with some funky sprites that need tending:

```
<style>
div.cartodb-popup.stories {width:317px;
    padding-top:5px;} 
div.cartodb-popup.stories div.cartodb-popup-content-wrapper{width:307px;
    max-width:307px;
    padding:0 5px;
    background: #ffffff;} 
div.cartodb-popup.stories div.cartodb-popup-tip-container{width:317px;} 
</style>
```